# Android Layout(User Interface)

Tags: android-layout

[image]

Hi i want to develop a UI like image, is it possible in android,if possible , how can we do that?(i need lines(horizontal and vertical) between images like image).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `LinearLayout` this layout is very simple.

Try below code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:weightSum="4"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:text="Find Dishes"

            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <View
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="3dp"
        android:background="@android:color/black" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
       android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:text="Recomanded Dishes"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <View
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="3dp"
        android:background="@android:color/black" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:weightSum="2" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="follow people"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <View
        android:layout_width="3dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/black" />
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="View Profile"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
 <View
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="3dp"
        android:background="@android:color/black" />

 <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:weightSum="2" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Notifications"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <View
        android:layout_width="3dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/black" />
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Sign up/Sign-In"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

After using this code my output is like this

[image]

change image and background according to your requirement.