# Creating a linearlayout with weights

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout

Im trying to make something similar to this - [Android Layout(User Interface)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13620991/android-layoutuser-interface) only I want to make the first column with a weight of 4 the second one with a weight of 2 (and also with two rows) and the last one with a weight of 1 (and also with three rows)...problem is It messes up itself (I copy and pasted the answer and changed everything according to my needs but it keeps on get messed up.. =) any help?
[code]

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@color/background_color"
    android:orientation="vertical"

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="4"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textDishes"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:text="@string/dishes"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageDishes"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <View
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/seperator_size"
        android:background="@color/seperator" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:measureWithLargestChild="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="2" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textfood"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/food"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imagefood"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <View
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/seperator_size"
            android:background="@color/seperator" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textMalls"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/malls"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageMalls"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <View
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/seperator_size"
        android:background="@color/seperator" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:weightSum="3"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/app_name"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <View
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/seperator_size"
            android:background="@color/seperator" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/coupons"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
        </LinearLayout>

         <View
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/seperator_size"
            android:background="@color/seperator" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/markets"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
[/code]
```

That is the result -

[image]

The result should look like - 
[image]
Any help??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**EDIT** working example now

This is not a complete answer because the vertical dividers are still not working, but hopefully it gets you going in the right direction:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="4"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textDishes"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Dishes"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageDishes"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
</LinearLayout>

<View
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="5dp"
    android:background="@color/red" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="2"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textfood"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Food"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imagefood"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <View
        android:layout_width="5dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="@color/red"
        android:gravity="center" >
    </View>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textMalls"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Malls"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageMalls"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>

<View
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="5dp"
    android:background="@color/red" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="App name"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <View
        android:layout_width="5dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="@color/red"
        android:gravity="center" >
    </View>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Coupons"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <View
        android:layout_width="5dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="@color/red"
        android:gravity="center" >
    </View>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Markets"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if this was just a mistake when you included your XML here, but you're missing a ">" after the parent LinearLayout.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@color/background_color"
android:orientation="vertical"
```

Should be

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@color/background_color"
android:orientation="vertical" >
```

Additionally, you are using weights in some of this parent layout's children, but you have not specified a weightSum total in the parent LinearLayout.  Remember that a weightSum is the total weight to be distributed amongst the children, so their weights should add up to this weightSum.  Also, just a head's up, but using nested weights (which you would be doing if you added that in) is bad for performance.

Maybe the best solution to your problem would be to explore a different layout option instead of using a LinearLayout?  You could get it to work this way, though.  Make the parent weightSum 7 and make sure you distribute this as desired to the children.

As per your picture (and using linear layouts), it should look something like this, I think:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:weightSum="7" >

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:weight="4" >

// This one's child here - it has weight 1.

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:weightSum="2"
    android:weight="2" >

// This one's children here - they both have weight 1.

 <LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:weightSum="3"
    android:weight="1" >

// This one's children here - they all have weight 1.
```

Don't forget to close the LinearLayouts as well.  I haven't tested that code, either, so you will want to review it for possible errors.

Comment: weightSum is not required

Comment: @invertigo - ahh, yeah, you're right, man.  It will just assume weightSum based on the weights that have been assigned.  I'm just really used to throwing weightSum in, but good call!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is your only problem but when using `weight` your `layout_width` should be "0dp" for a horizontal orientation and `layout_height` should be "0dp" for a vertical orientation. So for example your first child should be

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="4"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >
```

because it belongs to a parent `LinearLayout` who's `orientation` is `vertical`

**Update**

Something like this should get you really close. Note I had to take out your resources to make it work in my editor so you will just have to put those back in

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="4"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textDishes"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:text="Dishes"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageDishes"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
</LinearLayout>

<View
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dp" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="2"
    android:measureWithLargestChild="true"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="2" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textfood"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Food"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imagefood"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <View
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textMalls"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Malls"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageMalls"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>

<View
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dp" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:weightSum="3"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="App name"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <View
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Coupons"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
    </LinearLayout>

     <View
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Markets"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: How does it get screwed up? When I used that code it looked basically like that without the separators. You may want to try cleaning your project too...Project --> Clean

Comment: the problem is occurring as soon as you add one of the vertical dividers. there are also a few things wrong with this example, the first LL should be verical, not horizontal, and some of the dividers have width and height reversed.

Comment: @invertigo No, the `orientation` is correct. The first `LinearLayout` is vertical. I don't see any dividers backwards but I suppose it's possible...hard to tell without it in my editor anymore. But it gave me the output the OP was looking for without the dividers so they may need to be tweaked

Comment: i'm sorry, the first nested LL should be vertical (the dishes one)

Comment: @invertigo I see what you are saying now. Yes, according to the updated picture, yes, but when I posted I copied what he had assuming he knew the desired orientation. But that could be easily changed. My answer, at the time I posted, should have got him on his way with some tweaks, of course